# Capybara unable to find link "Delete Comment"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara

Here is the view
#views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<div class="comment clearfix">

  <div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</p>
  </div>

  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.email == ENV['ADMIN'] %>
    <p><%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, class: 'button', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %></p>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

here is the test...
#spec/features/03_comments_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'blog posts', %Q{
  As an unauthenticated user
  I want to create and delete comments
} do

  let!(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
  let!(:comment) { FactoryGirl.create(:comment, post: post) }

  scenario 'delete post comment', js: true do
    visit post_path(post)
    click_link 'Delete Comment'

    expect(page).to_not have_content(comment.name)
    expect(page).to_not have_content(comment.body)
  end
end
```

I thought it might have to due with detecting javascript as I have it being removed with a `destroy.js.erb` file.

#views/comments/destroy.js.erb

```
$('.comment').remove()
```

So I installed `phantomjs`

#support/database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.after(:each) do
  end
end
```

#spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require "capybara/poltergeist" 
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|    
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

When I run `rspec` the test fails with the following output

```
 Failure/Error: click_link 'Delete Comment'

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link "Delete Comment"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Delete Comment" link is only shown if the user is logged in (`if user_signed_in? && ...`), but nowhere in your test are you logging in the user - hence the link isn't actually on the page.

Comment: Oh good gravy, you're right. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you.